# Checkout Order Total summary went on refresh of checkout page Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipping-methods

I have rearrange the checkout summary block after the cart items and whenever i tried to refresh the page or i add a new address or switch between multiple addresses Order Total Summary block removed from page and i cant able to see any totals.